# For each loop not returning values?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, each

I'm currently making a programme that requires me to check my words in an array against all the words in a text file (dictionary) and return the value true if it is and false if it isn't.
This is my code so far

```
 public static boolean isEnglishWord(String[] arrayOfWords) throws IOException {
     for (String line : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("words.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
         if(arrayOfWords[0] == line)
         {
             return true;
         }
         else
         {
             return false;
         }
     }
     return false;
    }
```

I know the this only checks the first word in the 'line', I'm wondering how to move onto the next word to compare it against my word in the array

Comment: 1. Don't use `==` on strings. 2. `if (x) return true; else return false;` is a very verbose synonym for `return x`. 3. Only return `true` if you find something, so delete the `else` clause.

Comment: Remove if and else condition and simply return -> return (arrayOfWords[0].equalsIgnoreCase(line))

Comment: Your method makes no sense. isEnglishWord sounds like a function that checks, whether one word is an english word, not whether a whole list of Strings contains an English word. Either change the method name or only accept a single string as a parameter.

Comment: @barq I was just merely testing the first word in my array, I am now going through the whole array of words to see if they're all english words.

Comment: Then you should only pass that word to your function, not the whole array.

Comment: @barq I know, it was just a sample testing to see if it actually worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove this part :

```
public static boolean isEnglishWord(String[] arrayOfWords) throws IOException {
     for (String line : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("words.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
         if(arrayOfWords[0].equals(line)) // use `equals()` instead of `==`
         {
             return true;
         }
      //   else    --> If word is not found, you will eventually return false
       //  {
       //      return false;
       //  }
     }
     return false;
    }
```

Comment: Better compare Strings with arrayOfWords[0].equalsIgnoreCase(line)

Comment: @exoddus - The OP has not specified *that*. :)

Answer (score 2):

Apart from fixing your code in the obvious way, you can also consider stepping up to the Java 8 idiom:

```
return Files.lines(Paths.get("words.txt"), UTF_8)
            .anyMatch(w1 -> Stream.of(arrayOfWords)
                                  .anyMatch(w2 -> w2.equals(w1)));
```

And further, a typical optimization which would transform your O(n<sup>2</sup>) algorithm into O(n) is to use a `Set<String>` instead of the string array:

```
final Set<String> setOfWords = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(arrayOfWords));
```

then you'd write

```
return Files.lines(Paths.get("words.txt"), UTF_8)
            .anyMatch(setOfWords::contains);
```

Alternatively, if space is a concern, you could just sort the array and use the JDK-provided binary search on it, resulting in O(n log n) complexity:

```
Arrays.sort(arrayOfWords);
```

and

```
return Files.lines(Paths.get("words.txt"), UTF_8)
            .anyMatch(w -> Arrays.binarySearch(arrayOfWords, w) >= 0);
```

Finally, it looks like what you really want to check is that *all* the words in the file are English words, not that the file contains at least one such word. After the above refactoring that logic stands out quite clearly and is now easy to change by replacing just two characters:

```
return Files.lines(Paths.get("words.txt"), UTF_8)
            .allMatch(setOfWords::contains);
```

... which is a nice demonstration of how the conciseness of the FP idiom makes your code more obvious and easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

First of all use `equals` when comparing Strings. Second of all, use a nested loop :

```
public static boolean isEnglishWord(String[] arrayOfWords) throws IOException {
    for (String line : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("words.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
        for (String word : arrayOfWords) {
            if(word.equals(line))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is assuming your method only has to match a single word from the entire file with a single word from the array in order to return true. I'm not sure how useful that method is.

Answer (score 0):

You are only checking for the first word in the arrayOfWords. You need two loops in order to check all words in the file against all words in arrayOfWords.

```
public static boolean isEnglishWord(String[] arrayOfWords) throws IOException {
     for (String line : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("words.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
         for (String word: arrayOfWords)
            return word.equalsIgnoreCase(line);    
     }
     return false;
}
```